# C# System.Threading.Mutex System.Threading.Mutex.OpenExisting Method Not found

Tags: c#, multithreading, cpu-usage

I'm attempting to make a C# script to send CPU temp and usage statistics to a raspberry pi (it's an LED cube project). I tried to use Python to do it, but the library it used, psutil, does not support sensor readings on Windows.

I'm using the OpenHardwareMonitorLib dll file to try and get the CPU stats. owever, it throws an error won the lines "Computer computer = new Computer(); computer.Open();". The error is:

"System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'System.Threading.Mutex System.Threading.Mutex.OpenExisting(System.String, System.Security.AccessControl.MutexRights)'.'"

I've tried everything I can think of and everything I have found on google. I can't remember them all, but these are some of them:

- Installing Powershell 7
- Adding the SystemManagement.dll file to the project (which got me past the previous error to this one)
- Installing the newest .NET 4.8 and *all* of the extras around it.
- Added a requirement to run as Admin to the app manifest.

I've put the code on Github (https://github.com/verdammte/led_cube), but here's the C# code in question:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware;

namespace Get_CPU_Temp5
{
    class Program
    {
        public class UpdateVisitor : IVisitor
        {
            public void VisitComputer(IComputer computer)
            {
                computer.Traverse(this);
            }
            public void VisitHardware(IHardware hardware)
            {
                hardware.Update();
                foreach (IHardware subHardware in hardware.SubHardware) subHardware.Accept(this);
            }
            public void VisitSensor(ISensor sensor) { }
            public void VisitParameter(IParameter parameter) { }
        }
        static void GetSystemInfo()
        {
            UpdateVisitor updateVisitor = new UpdateVisitor();
            Computer computer = new Computer();
            computer.Open();
            computer.CPUEnabled = true;
            computer.Accept(updateVisitor);
            for (int i = 0; i < computer.Hardware.Length; i++)
            {
                if (computer.Hardware[i].HardwareType == HardwareType.CPU)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < computer.Hardware[i].Sensors.Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (computer.Hardware[i].Sensors[j].SensorType == SensorType.Temperature)
                            Console.WriteLine(computer.Hardware[i].Sensors[j].Name + ":" + computer.Hardware[i].Sensors[j].Value.ToString() + "\r");
                    }
                }
            }
            computer.Close();
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                GetSystemInfo();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All I want to do is get the CPU usage and CPU temperature and send them to a remote IP. I feel like this shouldn't be this hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based off your repository it looks like your console app is targeting `.NET Core` but that `.dll` you are referencing is in `.NET Framework`. Try creating your project in `.NET Framework 4.5+`.

Comment: Can do. I'll try it in the morning. I'd do it now, but Windows is pissed at me for not letting it interrupt me earlier to update. Thanks! I'll let you know if it works

Comment: dude/dudette, you're the best. I honestly had no clue I was using .NET core. I've only ever used the .NET framework and I thought I'd done the same this time. I would have never thought to check that.

Comment: It would be nice to be able to use DotNetFW from DotNetCore, but I suppose it defeats the purpose. I'm attempting to do the same thing, but want it to be cross platform, but Dotnet7 is still not fully cross-platform, so there you have it.